# Fancybox doesn't work when opened on a consecutive page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my project I have apartments and groups of photos that belong to each of the apartment. On an apartment show page I want to create galleries using fancybox.  When I open the show page fancybox doesn't work, though if I refresh this page everything works perfectly. As I understand jQuery is called only once when the website is loaded, but not called when just a new page is opened. To try to solve this I've put jQuery on the show page and use `$(window).ready(function())`, but it still doesn't work. Please help.
Here is my show.html.erb:

```
<script>
$(window).ready(function() {    
  $("a.gallery").fancybox({
    'padding' : '0',
    'cyclic'  : true,
    'hideOnContentClick' : true,
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none'
  });
});
</script>

<% @pin.pics.each do |x| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(x.image.url(:thumb)), 
  x.image.url(:large),
  :class => "gallery", :rel => "group#{x.pin_id}" %>
<% end %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Описание:</strong>
  <%= @pin.description %>
</p>
<% if @pin.user == current_user %>
  <%= link_to 'Редактировать', edit_pin_path(@pin) %> |
<% end %>   
<%= link_to 'Назад', pins_path %>
```

Comment: This "new page" of yours, is it loaded in ajax or something? if so, you can recall the plugin on ajax complete.

Comment: No, I don't use ajax (basically because I don't know it). So when I say a new page is loaded, I mean I open it in the browser

Comment: Alright, so there's a server request and a pageload as well. Where do you put the <script> with fancybox plugin, and where is located the script you provided in the question? Please do note, it's $(document).ready, i'm not sure it will work with window, but give it a try. (if not, try "$(window).on('load', function() {});" )

Comment: I've put the <script>  I provided in the question in show.html.erb - the page that displays the gallery for this individual apartment. There is no fancybox plugin script per ce, as I'm using ruby on rails and used gem to install fancybox.

Comment: Oh, and yeah (window).ready works as well, I've checked.

Comment: And one more detail - when I've just created a new apartment, fancybox also works on the show page